# How to change slider widget price range text and "Go" label in KickStart Commerce?

Tags: commerce

How to change slider widget price range text and "Go" label in KickStart Commerce?[image]

Want to remove "range from...." and change "Go" on the button to Russian "Найти".

What Drupal display view or template, page or module to change? Thank you (see fig. attached, please).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work around. See if it works :

- Create a file custom_string_overrides.inc  inside your custom module folder and add the below code:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Go' => 'Add replacement here',
  'range from' => 'Add replacement here',
);
```

- Add the below code to settings.php

```
include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/path-to-module/custom_string_overrides.inc';
```

The above trick does the string replacement and texts will be replaced where ever they appear. As I mentioned, this is just a workaround.